# Show $\tan(\pi x) − x − 6 = 0$ has a root between 0 and 1.

Tags: numerical-methods

Show $tan(\pi x) − x − 6 = 0$ has a root between $0$ and $1$

for this question when I plug in $0$ or $1$ as values for $x$, $f(x)$ gives the values of $-6$ and $-7$, respectively so because it does not appear to cross the x-axis, I cannot say there is a root between $0$ and $1$ using Intermediate Value Theorem.

Is there another method I should be using?

Comment: Hint: the tan function has asymptotes. Are there any for this function between $0$ and $1$?

Comment: The IVT does not apply here because $\tan(\pi x)$ is not defined at $x=\frac{1}{2}$ (and therefore not continous which is a crucial condition for IVT)

Comment: But we can see that at $x=0.5$ (infinity is positive) it is positive and for $x=0$ it is negative.

Comment: @Abhinav The sign in this case depends on which side of $0.5$ we are (if we are very near to $0.5$). So, to say that at $x=0.5$ , the value is positive, is not correct (even if we consider $\infty$ to be a "number"). Correct is : The limit for $x\rightarrow 0.5$ from the left is $+\infty$ and $f(0)<0$

Answer (score 1):

$\tan(x)$ can be written in terms of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$. We know that when $\sin(x)$ is almost at it’s maximum, $\cos(x)$ is almost zero (at what value is $\sin(x)$ at its maximum?). Since any number divided by a very small number is very large, it should be obvious that your function will reach positive values in that interval.

Answer (score 1):

When taking a test it is your job to eliminate any doubt about your abilities. If we cannot write clearly about simple matters, then we should not attempt to write about complicated matters.

---

Let $I = (-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$ and let $f : I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be given by $$f(x) = \tan(\pi x).$$
Then $$f(x) \rightarrow -\infty, \quad x \rightarrow -\frac{1}{2}, \quad x \in I$$
and $$f(x) \rightarrow \infty, \quad x \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}, \quad x \in I.$$
Let $g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be given by 
$$g(x) = x + 6.$$
Then $$ g(x) \rightarrow \frac{11}{2}, \quad x  \rightarrow -\frac{1}{2}, \quad x \in I$$ and 
$$ g(x) \rightarrow \frac{13}{2}, \quad x  \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}, \quad x \in I.$$
It follows that $h : I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$ h(x) = f(x) - g(x)$$
satisfies
$$ h(x) \rightarrow -\infty, \quad x \rightarrow -\frac{1}{2}, \quad x \in I$$
and 
$$ h(x) \rightarrow \infty, \quad x  \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}, \quad x \in I.$$
In particular, there exists $x_1, x_2 \in I$, such that $h(x_1) < 0$ and $h(x_2) > 0$. The function $h$ is continuous, because $h$ is the difference of two continuous functions. By the intermediate value property $h$ has a zero in  open interval between $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : $$f(0.4)<0$$ $$f(0.47)>0$$ and in the interval $[0.4,0.47]$ , $f$ is continous, so this time, you can apply IVT.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the intermediate value theorem between $0$ and $1$ as $tan(\pi{x})$ is undefined at $x=0.5$. However you can see that at $x=0$ it is negative. And at $x=0.5$ it is positive ($tan\frac{\pi}{2}$ is positive even though it is undefined). So using the intermediate value theorem between $0$ and $0.5$ we see that there is a root between it. So there is a root between $0$ and $1$ also.